# Wanting to convert a string

Tags: javascript

So I have this code in which I am attempting to create a simple calculator:

```
window.onload = function () {make_buttons ('calc'); }

function make_buttons (id) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(id);
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = 'text'; input.id = 'inp';
        parent.appendChild(input);
        for (var i = 0;i < 10; i++){
            var btn = document.createElement ("button");
            btn.innerHTML = i;
            btn.id = i;
            parent.appendChild(btn);
            (function(index) {btn.onclick = function() {input.value += index;}})(i);
        }

        var multiply = document.createElement ("button");
        multiply.innerHTML = "*";
        multiply.id = "*";
        parent.appendChild(multiply);
        multiply.onclick = function () {input.value += '*';};
        var divide = document.createElement ("button");
        divide.innerHTML = "/";
        divide.id = "/";
        parent.appendChild(divide);
        divide.onclick = function () {input.value += '/';};
        var add = document.createElement ("button");
        add.innerHTML = "+";
        add.id = "+";
        parent.appendChild(add);
        add.onclick = function () {input.value += '+';};
        var substract = document.createElement ("button");
        substract.innerHTML = "-";
        substract.id = "-";
        parent.appendChild(substract);
        substract.onclick = function () {input.value += '-';};
        var calc_it = document.createElement ("button");
        calc_it.innerHTML = "=";
        calc_it.id = "=";
        parent.appendChild(calc_it);
        calc_it.onclick = function () {calculate ()};

};

function calculate () {
    var info = document.getElementById ('inp').value;
    console.log(info);


};
```

So right now when I click the buttons and make the input field have 5 * 5 inside of it for instance - the var info will equal a string "5 * 5".  How could I convert this string so that the numbers in the string will be integers and the operators like * or - will also be non string?

Do I need to include some regex code here?

Comment: the horribly bad way of doing it: `eval('5 * 5')`...

Comment: Ehh... I would really like to avoid that way.

Comment: try regex... or keep appending the digits to a variable and on any operator press, convert the string variable to int or float... this way you will have all the parts... it's like building the expression as you type in the calculator...

Comment: stop thinking that eval is *always* evil. Here there's no way some javascript code can slip in the evaled expression, which is built out of the button press, so security risk is === 0.  Eval is perfect.

Comment: So if I convert "*" which is a string to a int, I will be able to use it in a calculation?

Comment: But if I write something javascriptish into the input field, will it not execute it with eval?

Comment: Do you really think hackers from around the globe and the NSA will try to hack your app to retrieve your credit card number and your secret birthday photos ? Yes : do not use eval or filter keyborad input to limit it to numbers and operators. No : use eval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is a difficult one indeed. The obvious and most unpopular answer is an eval, but most likely you are not going to want that.

Basically you will have to code a routine to extract anything you want to use in the expression.

Without using eval or a 3rd party library like 'silentmatts' solution ( below ) you may have to develop your own routine to parse the data.

3rd Party Solution:

Site: http://silentmatt.com/javascript-expression-evaluator/

Git: https://github.com/silentmatt/js-expression-eval

With all of that said, as far as turning a string into a mathematical equation, i personally use eval.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Allright, I will try to fiddle a bit more and see if I can manage to do it without eval then.